# How to save/access current iPhone background image

Tags: iphone

I lost my background image file from my gallery. I would ask you if do you know a way to save the actual background image? I don't want to lose it.

Comment: is it in recently deleted album ? Is iCloud syncing turned on ? if yes, then turn off cellular and wifi and get the image from iCloud or other devices.

Comment: unfortunately no. I don't delate recently.